# Append fancybox class to element with existing class

Tags: html, fancybox

I want to add fancybox v2 to a link on my website:

```
<p class="buttontext">
    <a href="http://google.com" class="fancybox" class="buttontextlink">Education</a>
</p>
```

but as you can see the link already has a class with stylistic elements associated with it

How can I add fancybox to it without having to sacrifice `class="buttontextlink"`?

Comment: That is HTML basics… See xnm's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking. If you want to have two classes associated with an html element, you just add a space between them:

```
<p class="buttontext"><a href="http://google.com"  class="fancybox buttontextlink">Education</a></p>
```

Comment: +1 works like a charm - I am not great with html - I am more of a python guy ;)

Comment: 8 min. and the answer will be yours

Comment: No worries. Just wasn't sure if it was an html question or a jquery/javascript one.